# error: redefinition of 'paddlePlayer'

Tags: c++

I keep getting this error:

> `redefinition of 'paddlePlayer' paddlePlayer::paddlePlayer(int playerNumber)`

I also get the error:

> `out-of-line definition of 'Update' does not match any declaration in 'paddlePlayer'
>   void paddlePlayer::Update()`

My cpp file is as follows:

```
#include "paddleplayer.h"

paddlePlayer::paddlePlayer(int playerNumber)
{
    this->playerNumber = playerNumber;
    switch (this->playerNumber)
    {
        case 0:
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

void paddlePlayer::Update()
{
    switch (this->playerNumber)
    {
        case 0:
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

And my header file looks like this:

```
#ifndef HAND_IN_5_1_PADDLEPLAYER_H
#define HAND_IN_5_1_PADDLEPLAYER_H

#include "entity.h"

class paddlePlayer : public Entity
{
public:
    paddlePlayer(int playerNumber)
    {
        this->playerNumber = playerNumber;
        void Update();

    }

protected:
    int playerNumber;
};

#endif
```

Any tips?

Comment: Your constructor is defined both in the header and the .cpp, and the declaration for `Update()` is inside the constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theres a few errors in your header:

```
#ifndef HAND_IN_5_1_PADDLEPLAYER_H
#define HAND_IN_5_1_PADDLEPLAYER_H

#include "entity.h"

class paddlePlayer : public Entity
{
public:
    paddlePlayer(int _playerNumber); //Wasn't declared correctly and you shouldn't give the same name to a parameter that is an attribute of your class
    void Update(); // Was declared inside your constructor definition...

protected:
    int playerNumber;
};
```